# How Do I Correct a ByRef Mismatch Error in VBA for Worksheet_Change Sub in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a process that currently involves clicking a button on an Excel Sheet called "Fix UPC". This button looks at a text-formatted string to see if it is 12 characters long, if so, it will delete the last digit and then set the number format to "0-00000-00000". The vast majority of the UPCs this sheet will deal with follow the UPC-A standard, but like a lot of systems, ours ignores the last check digit, hence the need to trim it to 11 so a  VLOOKUP will work properly. A few follow the 13-digit EAN standard so those need to be left intact.

Right now I have the following function located in a module named `Helpers`:

```
Public Function deleteCheckDigit(theUPC) As String
    If Len(theUPC) = 12 Then
        deleteCheckDigit = Left(theUPC, 11)
    Else
        deleteCheckDigit = theUPC
    End If
End Function
```

The Private Sub on the Worksheet is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    theCol = Helpers.GetColumnFromAddress(Target.Address)
    theValue = Range(Target.Address).Value
    
    If theCol = "A" Then
        If Len(theValue) = 12 Then
            Target.Value = Helpers.deleteCheckDigit(theValue)
            Range(Target.Address).NumberFormat = "0-00000-00000"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When I enter in a UPC and hit Enter, Excel throws a Compile Error stating `ByRef argument type mismatch`. I tested `VarType(theValue)` and it returns `8` meaning it is a string, so I am not seeing what is causing this error.

Note: I have this set up with an `If/Then` block to check the column letter because there is some other modifications being done to different columns.

Comment: Try declare the function parameter `deleteCheckDigit(theUPC As String)' and call it as `deleteCheckDigit(CStr(theValue))`

Comment: This is going to fail if you change multiple cells simultaneously. Also `Range(Target.Address)` should be simplified to just `Target`. Also your check for if `Target` falls in column A is overcomplicated. Instead of using the column letter, use the column *index*. Also it's safer to temporarily disable events since you're changing the worksheet within the Change event handler.

Comment: Not your problem, but use `theValue = Target.Value` and  If `Target.Column = 1 Then`. No need to work with addresses or column characters in VBA

Comment: The use of the letters is just to make it more friendly to the person who will have to maintain this should I leave the company. I'm trying to match up everything in the code to reference what they see on the sheet.

Comment: How is `.Column = 1` not "friendly"? IMO, you're doing this person a disservice by overcomplicating this.

Comment: @BigBen Because Excel labels columns on the worksheet itself using letters. Also, this isn't going to be set up for multiple users to simultaneously enter things in. It's on a local, shared computer. The only other way to to have it with multiple users is to use the Scan-it-to-Office phone app, but that targets an identical sheet with a different name and we've ceased using it since it's not something corporate will pay for.

Comment: @FaneDuru That worked. If you want to create an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Cedon - of course. Yet `=COLUMN(A1)` returns `1`, not `A`. And `Range("A1").Column` returns `1`, not `A`. You created an entirely new function that is unnecessary. Using the column letter is an antipattern.

Comment: Ive also learned to drop column letters due to situations where youre moving in reference to a non-A1 starting point. Like from the top left of a table.  `With Range("D4"): .Range("B2")...` This wont actually be "B2" it will be "E5". So column letters become way more confusing than numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`Len` of a string returns what you need. But `Len` of a number returns differently...

So, it would be good to declare the function parameter `deleteCheckDigit(theUPC As String)` and and call it casting the argument
like `deleteCheckDigit(CStr(theValue))`, to be sure that a `String` is sent to the function.

It will also be good to **ALWAYS** declare all used variables, respectively:

```
  Dim theCol As Sring
  Dim theValue As String
```

Doing it and using `Option Explicit` on top of the module, you are warned if a typo will appear, by mistake. Something as `theVal`. In such a case you can call the function like `deleteCheckDigit(theValue)`, `theValue` being already converted to `String`.

About the dispute regarding using of the column letter or number, it depends on the people skills to debug the code. They are similar and I also prefer using the column number, but using its letter may be more eloquent for a less skilled  operator trying to understand and debug the code...